# link_to on a black with couple of paramerts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i am trying to generate a href tag. 
this is how i want it 
`<a href = "events/index?start=12&end=1" > 12(start) - 1(End)  </a>`

i tried various combination but not able to do it , please help

I am trying to pass two parameters into link_to  tag.

> _event.html.erb
>
> `<%= link_to(events_path , {  start: event.start , end: event.end  },{id:"abc"}) do %>
>
> <%= event.start %> - <%= event.end %> 
>   <% end %>`

thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
 link_to  "#{event.start} - #{event.end}" , events_paths(start: event.start , end: event.end)
```

With block, you can do something like

```
 link_to  events_paths(start: event.start , end: event.end)  do 
   "#{event.start} - #{event.end}"
 end
```

Comment: yes but i want to generate the link based on start and end time. <a href=".." > 12 - 1 </a>

Comment: what `html` it suppose to generate ?

Comment: <a href= "events/index?start=12&end=1"> 12 - 1 </a> , 12 and 1 are event.start and event.end of the parameter passed into the partial

Comment: yes worked perfectly .. thanks a lot .. one question if i want to do it using do end block. how can we do that. ?

Comment: let me know the feedback.

Comment: `
 <%= link_to   events_path(start: event.start , end: event.end) do %>
   <%= event.start %>(Start) - <%= event.end %>(End)
 <% end -%>'  This worked ...

Comment: looks like you have changed your needs. that's disgusting

Comment: fundamentals are same i just changed the format after you answered the first query... i dont see why this is disgusting ..anyways your solution was helpful.. i read your blog after that i was not expecting such comments from you..